# How to use MetaPost with TeXlipse?

Tags: tools, metapost, texlipse

I would like to to use TeXlipse, MetaPost and MetaUML to generate requirements specifications. The problem I have is that I haven't found an easy way to incorporate MetaPost in TeXlipse build. There is configuration for common TeX tools, preferred output format and toolchain to produce it, but MetaPost is not there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can write directly Metapost source in the LaTeX file, loading the **mpgraphics** or the **gmp** package. Both require that the `-shell-escape` feature is enabled, but the second package can work also without it (and produces a shell script to be run after LaTeX compilation).

Disclaimer: I'm **gmp**'s author.

Comment: I found a workaround, but I will look into it later and let you know, thank you for an answer.